# How do I build and link libCurl in VS project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, curl, libcurl

I am trying to use cURL in a C++ project I am working on in VS2010.

I downloaded the latest cURL source and I am building the solution included in the archive. When I build this project the only output lib appears to be "libcurld_imp.lib". I was expecting a "libcul.lib". In any case I have pointed VS to the include directory where the headers live and added the above mentioned lib to my linker's dependencies. Finally, I add the folder path of this "libcurld_imp.lib" to the links additional libraries search locations.

I cannot build my project because of the following linker error:

error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libcurld_imp.lib'

This file does exist in a folder that I added to the linker's additional libraries search path. What am I missing? Thanks

**update**

Ok.. So was able to get a libcurl.lib file by editing the libcurl proj. The default build settings were set to output a DLL. I changed this to as static library. Now that I have a libcurl.lib I am getting these linking errors:

Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_curl_easy_setopt referenced in function _main
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_curl_easy_perform referenced in function _main

Anyone know how to link this friggen thing?

**Another update**

The documentation included in the source download includes a file, "build.windows". The directions say to build the lib using the following command:

nmake /f makefile.vc mode=

I have done this using "static" as my mode and "VC=10" as my option. This builds the library but it is called libcurl_a.lib. Linking to this lib gives the same errors :( 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the _`imp` suffix in `libcurld_imp.lib` most likely stands for *Import Library*. You are building a DLL and this file is the lib you need to link to your exe to call the DLL implicitely.

The solution should contain other configurations that will let you build a static library.

Comment: Thanks.. I would prefer to not have the external dependency of a dll. But I will continue to try and get a static lib built.

Comment: maybe the question was updated, but the question asker highlights imp, which means that the .lib is not a static library containing that function, but has just a stub for linking with a .dll. he also points out that he built the static configuration. i've hit exactly the same problem so i can verify this...

Answer (score 0):

You need both to succeed. Try this suggestion (it's for vs2008 but should work):

http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2009-05/0097.html

Comment: They both are succeeding. I will try this post however.